# 'n-minute walk' for other forms of transportation

Tags: idioms, expressions

I'm familiar with the expression *n-minute walk* to describe something at a 10-minute distance by foot, but I was stuck when I tried to use this expression with other kinds of transportation. For example, if I want to express something apart by 10-minute distance by bus, how can I express that in a similar way to *n-minute walk*?

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> a ten-mile **trip** by bus
>
> a ten-mile **drive** by car
>
> a thousand-mile **flight** by plane

etc. The travel descriptor changes depending on the mode of transportation.

Comment: It could also be `a ten minute bus ride`.

Comment: This can also describe the time as in the OP. For example, six-hour flight. Also, **three-day cruise** by ship.